# Connect a Vandal Switch with Raspberry-Pi and register an Input/Output with a click

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, gpio, gpiozero

I want to connect a Vandal Switch(CPS) with an Raspberry Pi, there i want to register via an Phython program when the Button is Pressed and change the Led light from blue to Red.

How i connected the Cables to the Raspberry Pi:

- `Brown cable -> 5V Power`
- `Black cable -> Ground`
- `Black cable -> Ground`
- `white cable 1 -> GPIO5`
- `White cable 2 -> GPIO6`
- `Green cable (green LED) -> GPIO2`
- `Blue cable (blue LED) -> GPIO3`
- `Red cable (red LED) -> GPIO4`

I´ve tried this in phyton on the Raspberry Pi:

```
from gpiozero import Button, LED
from signal import pause

led = LED(3)
button = Button(5)

button.when_pressed = led.on
button.when_pressed = led.off
pause()
```

Error: No module named "gpiozero"

I've installed the module via console command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phyton-gpiozero
```

(it says that it is already on the newest version)

Comment: Could this example work ? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you already looked at [raspberrypi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)? Your question seems to be more relevant there.

Comment: You asked this exact same question here: [How to connect a Vandal Switch with Raspberry Pi and register a click?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64121615/2745495). Please don't repost duplicate questions. The previous one is now reopened and is accepting answers. On topics that are not highly active or don't have a lot of users following it, it may take time to get responses.